# How do I change the caption of my subfigures into normal letters but not capital letters?

Tags: captions

This is my simplified code:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens, labelsep=none}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c][4.5cm][c]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Figure1}
        \captionof{subfigure}{}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c][10.8cm][t]{.45\textwidth}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure2}
        \captionof{subfigure}{}
        \par\vfill
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Figure3}
        \captionof{subfigure}{}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c][10.8cm][t]{.55\textwidth}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.94\textwidth, height=9.5cm]{Figure4}
        \captionof{subfigure}{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{(a) (b) (c) (d)}
    \label{figure:1}
\end{figure}
```

For some reason, the caption of my subfigure turns out to be (A), (B), (C) instead of (a), (b), (c). Did I miss out anything?

For reference, I used the minipage environment because I need to arrange my figures in this way:
[image]

Comment: Why do you use a combination of minipage environments with \captionof{subfigure} instead of subfigure environments and \caption commands?

Comment: Uhm I used the minipage environments because of the image arrangement that I'm trying to achieve. I've tried and search for ways to arrange it in such a way, and ended up only workable using the minipage environment. I will edit my original post and add in the configuration that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `\begin{subfigure}{<dimen>}...\end{subfigure}` is equivalent to a `minipage`, but also allows `\caption` inside it instead of the clumsy `\captionof`. You have four subfigures, but show only three of them in the example layout.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the reason why I was not able to use the subfigure environment was because of the good old clashing between subfigure and subcaption packages that I just can't find a way to solve for now. Spent the whole night yesterday looking for solutions but have not been able to solve it. Which is why I ended up using the minipage environment which somehow worked, just that the subcaption went haywire.

Comment: @Chew - The `subfigure` environment (provided by the `subcaption`  package) *is*, for all intents and purposes, a `minipage` environment -- one that's been informed what to do if it encounters a  `\caption` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.25ex, belowskip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.9\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    
    \smallskip
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=1.37\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
\caption{(a) (b) (c) (d)}
\label{figure:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you see, used are just default settings for `subfigure` with which are replaced `minipage` environments used in your code fragment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the potential solution! I've actually tried using the subcaption package, but it clashes with the subfigure package that I'm also using. I have also spent quite some time to look for solutions on the forum, but have not been able to solve it yet. This is why I'm not using the subcaption package for the time being. The subfigure environment needs the \usepackage{subcaption} in the preamble right?

Comment: @Chew, `subfigure` is obsolete package and replaced by `subfig`, but better is used `subcaption`. Recent version of `subcaption` also support syntax of `subfig` (which differ from syntax of `subfigure`).

Comment: @Chew - The `subfigure` package is badly deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or `subcaption` package.

Comment: I see. May I ask, if I wish to change from subfigure to subcaption, can I just change the line `\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}` in my cls file, to `\usepackage[scriptsize]{subcaption}`?

Comment: @Chew, that simple is not. See preamble in my answer, where are defined only skip above/below captions, more desired options are described in package documentation (font size, formatting, etc. `caption`/`subcaption` combination are very powerful packages).